# Based on Partial string Match fill one data frame column from another dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

i'm new to python programming. I have two dataframes df1 containing tags (180k rows) and df2 containing equipment names (1600 rows)

df1:

> ```
>           Line                TagName                CLASS 
> 187877    PT_WOA  .ZS01_LA120_T05.SB.S2384_LesSwL     10
> 187878    PT_WOA  .ZS01_RB2202_T05.SB.S2385_FLOK      10
> 187879    PT_WOA  .ZS01_LA120_T05.SB._CBAbsHy         10
> 187880    PT_WOA  .ZS01_LA120_T05.SB.S3110_CBAPV      10
> 187881    PT_WOA  .ZS01_LARB2204.SB.S3111_CBRelHy     10
> ```

df2:

```
EquipmentNo EquipmentDescription    Equipment
1311256        Lifting table         LA120
1311257        Roller bed            RB2200
1311258        Lifting table         LT2202
1311259        Roller bed            RB2202
1311260        Roller bed            RB2204
```

The df2.Equipment is somewhere in between the strings in df1.TagName. i need to match based on if df2 Equipment is in df1 Tagname then df2 (Equipment description and Equipment no ) has to be matched with df1.

Final output should be

```
        Line                TagName                quipmentdescription   EquipmentNo 
187877  PT_WOA  .ZS01_LA120_T05.SB.S2384_LesSwL     Lifting table        1311256
187878  PT_WOA  .ZS01_RB2202_T05.SB.S2385_FLOK      Roller bed           1311259  
187879  PT_WOA  .ZS01_LA120_T05.SB._CBAbsHy         Lifting table        1311256 
187880  PT_WOA  .ZS01_LA120_T05.SB.S3110_CBAPV      Lifting table        1311256
 187881 PT_WOA  .ZS01_LARB2204.SB.S3111_CBRelHy     Roller bed           1311260
```

I have tried this now

```
cols= df2['Equipment'].tolist()
Xs=[]
for i in cols:
    Test = df1.loc[df1.TagName.str.contains(i)] 
    Test['Equip']=i
    Xs.append(Test)
```

then merge xs and df2 based on "Equipment"

But i am getting this error

> first argument must be string or compiled pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

1. Create a new column `indexes` where for every `Equipment` in df2 find a list of Indexes in df1 where df1.TagName contains the `Equipment`.
2. Flatten the `indexes` by creating one row for each item using `stack()` and `reset_index()`
3. Join the flatten df2 with df1 to get all information you want

```
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df1=StringIO("""Line;TagName;CLASS
187877;PT_WOA;.ZS01_LA120_T05.SB.S2384_LesSwL;10
187878;PT_WOA;.ZS01_RB2202_T05.SB.S2385_FLOK;10
187879;PT_WOA;.ZS01_LA120_T05.SB._CBAbsHy;10
187880;PT_WOA;.ZS01_LA120_T05.SB.S3110_CBAPV;10
187881;PT_WOA;.ZS01_LARB2204.SB.S3111_CBRelHy;10""")
df2=StringIO("""EquipmentNo;EquipmentDescription;Equipment
1311256;Lifting table;LA120
1311257;Roller bed;RB2200
1311258;Lifting table;LT2202
1311259;Roller bed;RB2202
1311260;Roller bed;RB2204""")
df1=pd.read_csv(df1,sep=";")
df2=pd.read_csv(df2,sep=";")

df2['indexes'] = df2['Equipment'].apply(lambda x: df1.index[df1.TagName.str.contains(str(x)).tolist()].tolist())
indexes = df2.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['indexes']),axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
indexes.name = 'indexes'
df2 = df2.drop('indexes', axis=1).join(indexes).dropna()
df2.index = df2['indexes']
matches = df2.join(df1, how='inner')
print(matches[['Line','TagName','EquipmentDescription','EquipmentNo']])
```

OUTPUT:

```
          Line                          TagName EquipmentDescription  EquipmentNo
187877  PT_WOA  .ZS01_LA120_T05.SB.S2384_LesSwL        Lifting table      1311256
187879  PT_WOA      .ZS01_LA120_T05.SB._CBAbsHy        Lifting table      1311256
187880  PT_WOA   .ZS01_LA120_T05.SB.S3110_CBAPV        Lifting table      1311256
187878  PT_WOA   .ZS01_RB2202_T05.SB.S2385_FLOK           Roller bed      1311259
187881  PT_WOA  .ZS01_LARB2204.SB.S3111_CBRelHy           Roller bed      1311260
```

Comment: Getting this Error "'float' object has no attribute 'replace'"   1 Test['indexes'] = Test['Equip'].apply(lambda x: Data.index[Data.TagName.str.contains(x.replace(" ","")).tolist()].tolist())

Comment: @Nandan it seems you column 'Equip' is of type float, it should be string type

Comment: try copying and pasting my solution, just to check it works for you. If it does, probably you have to double check the type of your original dataset

Comment: that's odd, I edited my answer... try to call str(x) instead of  x.replace(" ","")... but pandas is converting this column to float

Comment: `indexes = df2.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['indexes']),axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)` causes a `DeprecationWarning:`

Comment: I didn't get a DeprecationWarning, what specifically they mention to be deprecated ?

Comment: thank you very much  and can you explain me whats happening in these two line    df2['indexes'] = df2['Equipment'].apply(lambda x: df1.index[df1.TagName.str.contains(x.replace(" ","")).tolist()].tolist())
indexes = df2.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['indexes']),axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
indexes.name = 'indexes'

Comment: @Bernardostearnsreisen That's probably because I'm using pandas 1.0.3 and you're on an older version, or you have warnings suppressed.

Answer (score 1):

Initializing the provided dataframes:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['PT_WOA', '.ZS01_LA120_T05.SB.S2384_LesSwL', 10],
                    ['PT_WOA', '.ZS01_RB2202_T05.SB.S2385_FLOK', 10],
                    ['PT_WOA', '.ZS01_LA120_T05.SB._CBAbsHy', 10],
                    ['PT_WOA', '.ZS01_LA120_T05.SB.S3110_CBAPV', 10],
                    ['PT_WOA', '.ZS01_LARB2204.SB.S3111_CBRelHy', 10]],
                   columns = ['Line', 'TagName', 'CLASS'],
                   index = [187877, 187878, 187879, 187880, 187881])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1311256, 'Lifting table', 'LA120'],
                    [1311257, 'Roller bed', 'RB2200'],
                    [1311258, 'Lifting table', 'LT2202'],
                    [1311259, 'Roller bed', 'RB2202'],
                    [1311260, 'Roller bed', 'RB2204']],
                  columns = ['EquipmentNo', 'EquipmentDescription', 'Equipment'])
```

I would suggest the following:

```
# create a copy of df1, dropping the 'CLASS' column
df3 = df1.drop(columns=['CLASS'])

# add the columns 'EquipmentDescription' and 'Equipment' filled with numpy NaN's
df3['EquipmentDescription'] = np.nan
df3['EquipmentNo'] = np.nan

# for each row in df3, iterate over each row in df2
for index_df3, row_df3 in df3.iterrows():
    for index_df2, row_df2 in df2.iterrows():

        # check if 'Equipment' is in 'TagName'
        if df2.loc[index_df2, 'Equipment'] in df3.loc[index_df3, 'TagName']:

            # set 'EquipmentDescription' and 'EquipmentNo'
            df3.loc[index_df3, 'EquipmentDescription'] = df2.loc[index_df2, 'EquipmentDescription']
            df3.loc[index_df3, 'EquipmentNo'] = df2.loc[index_df2, 'EquipmentNo']


# conver the 'EquipmentNo' to type int
df3['EquipmentNo'] = df3['EquipmentNo'].astype(int)
```

This yields the following dataframe:

```
        Line    TagName                         EquipmentDescription EquipmentNo
187877  PT_WOA  .ZS01_LA120_T05.SB.S2384_LesSwL Lifting table        1311256
187878  PT_WOA  .ZS01_RB2202_T05.SB.S2385_FLOK  Roller bed           1311259
187879  PT_WOA  .ZS01_LA120_T05.SB._CBAbsHy     Lifting table        1311256
187880  PT_WOA  .ZS01_LA120_T05.SB.S3110_CBAPV  Lifting table        1311256
187881  PT_WOA  .ZS01_LARB2204.SB.S3111_CBRelHy Roller bed           1311260
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: if df2.loc[index_df2, 'Equipment'] in df3.loc[index_df3, 'TagName']:   " 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not float"  im getting this Error

Comment: I assume you are only getting this error if you are also using observations not displayed here, namely because you have non-string observations for column 'Equipment' in df2. Try adding the line df2['Equipment'] = df2['Equipment'].astype(str) just after creating df2. Does this solve your error?

Answer (score 1):

- Given `df1` and `df2` as follows:

### `df1`

```py
|    | Line   | TagName                         |   CLASS |
|---:|:-------|:--------------------------------|--------:|
|  0 | PT_WOA | .ZS01_LA120_T05.SB.S2384_LesSwL |      10 |
|  1 | PT_WOA | .ZS01_RB2202_T05.SB.S2385_FLOK  |      10 |
|  2 | PT_WOA | .ZS01_LA120_T05.SB._CBAbsHy     |      10 |
|  3 | PT_WOA | .ZS01_LA120_T05.SB.S3110_CBAPV  |      10 |
|  4 | PT_WOA | .ZS01_LARB2204.SB.S3111_CBRelHy |      10 |
```

### `df2`

```py
|    |   EquipmentNo | EquipmentDescription   | Equipment   |
|---:|--------------:|:-----------------------|:------------|
|  0 |       1311256 | Lifting table          | LA120       |
|  1 |       1311257 | Roller bed             | RB2200      |
|  2 |       1311258 | Lifting table          | LT2202      |
|  3 |       1311259 | Roller bed             | RB2202      |
|  4 |       1311260 | Roller bed             | RB2204      |
```

1. Find the unique `equipment` from `Equipment` in `df2`

```py
equipment = df2.Equipment.unique().tolist()
```

2. Create an `Equipment` column in `df1` by finding a match in `equipment`

```py
df1['Equipment'] = df1['TagName'].apply(lambda x: ''.join([part for part in equipment if part in x]))
```

3. Merge on `Equipment` into final form

   - If you don't want the `Equipment` column in `df_final`, add `.drop(columns=['Equipment'])` to the end of the next line of code.

```py
df_final = df1[['Line', 'TagName', 'Equipment']].merge(df2, on='Equipment')
```

### `df_final`

```py
|    | Line   | TagName                         | Equipment   |   EquipmentNo | EquipmentDescription   |
|---:|:-------|:--------------------------------|:------------|--------------:|:-----------------------|
|  0 | PT_WOA | .ZS01_LA120_T05.SB.S2384_LesSwL | LA120       |       1311256 | Lifting table          |
|  1 | PT_WOA | .ZS01_LA120_T05.SB._CBAbsHy     | LA120       |       1311256 | Lifting table          |
|  2 | PT_WOA | .ZS01_LA120_T05.SB.S3110_CBAPV  | LA120       |       1311256 | Lifting table          |
|  3 | PT_WOA | .ZS01_RB2202_T05.SB.S2385_FLOK  | RB2202      |       1311259 | Roller bed             |
|  4 | PT_WOA | .ZS01_LARB2204.SB.S3111_CBRelHy | RB2204      |       1311260 | Roller bed             |
```